# Reload Pages on Windows store apps

Tags: windows, memory, windows-runtime

I have two pages, and when I navigate for the first time to second page and write on textbox I don't get any delay between key press and character is showed on textbox. But when I navigate to the first page with

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FirstPage))
```

and I try again navigate to second page and I repeat the previous steps, I obtain the delay, this delay increases whenever I navigate to second page.

Any idea how to solve this increase of delay?

Thanks.

Comment: Watch your memory usage. I would bet money you have a memory leak somewhere, likely when you navigate/instantiate your `FirstPage` by adding an event handler. Make sure that you are 'being a good citizen' as it is known and unhooking handlers on navigating from the page, or making sure that you only hook in once.

Comment: I can show you! 
I navigate from FirstPage to SecondPage like this:
            'if (await Facade.Instance.getPreferences() != null)
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
            else
            { //TODO
            }'

Comment: Does either page have an `OnNavigatedTo` override or have event handlers added in the constructor?

Comment: I solved my problem... I added a event handler, but this event is attached on LoadState of the page.

Comment: On contructor no! But on LoadState. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an event handler being attached in one of the methods called upon Navigation.

Look for one in `OnNavigatedTo`, `LoadState`, or the constructor.